# Refresh the showcaseview Android

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am using showcase view in one of my android application. What i need is to refresh the content title and content text, keeping the target as same. Can anyone know how to solve this . I tried view.invalidate(). but not successful.
Thanks

-Manoj

Comment: Could you please post your code also.

Comment: showcaseView.setTarget(Target.NONE);
showcaseView.setContentTitle("HELLO PRUDHVI");
showcaseView.setButtonText("Press Next");

/*On button click*/
void onClick(View view)
{
  /*Just change the content title*/
 showcaseView.setContentTitle("I Want to change the Title Here");
 showcaseView.setButtonText("Ok I got It");
}

Comment: Are you kidding? If not please update your question with the above code.